# Where do you get your news?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

I'm a software developer.  Many of us get our news from http://news.ycombinator.com

Where do cogsci people get their news from?  I'd like to read the latest trends and discoveries in cogsci research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how helpful my answer will be, but I get my "news" from scanning journals related to my interests.  I look through 1) broad review journals, 2) broad empirical journals and 3) more specific empirical journals.

In general, I find that popular media outlets do a poor job of reporting on research in psychology/neuroscience (but hopefully someone else has some idea of reliable/quality news outlets).

Broad review journals that I tend to look at include:

1. [Trends in Cognitive Sciences](http://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/home)
2. [Current Directions in Psychological Science](http://cdp.sagepub.com)
3. [Perspectives on Psychological Science](http://pps.sagepub.com)
4. [Emotion Review](http://emr.sagepub.com)
5. [Behavioral and Brain Sciences](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=BBS)
6. [Psychological Review](http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/rev/)
7. [Psychological Bulletin](http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/bul/)
8. [Psychological Inquiry](http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/hpli20/current)
9. [Personality and Social Psychology Review](http://psr.sagepub.com)

Then there are the broad empirical journals:

1. [Psychological Science](http://pss.sagepub.com)   (studies from this journal appear very often in the news)
2. [Clinical Psychological Science](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/publications/journals/clinical)
3. [Nature](http://www.nature.com) (usually hardcore neuroscience or behavioral economics)
4. [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org) (occasionally get a fun psych study here, which will be heavily advertised on the news)
5. [Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences](http://www.pnas.org) (PNAS has a good psychological and cognitive sciences section)
6. [Neuroimage](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/neuroimage/)
7. [Journal of Personality and Social Psychology](http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/psp/)

And the more specific empirical journals (for me, mostly related to emotion):

1. [Emotion](http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/emo/)
2. [Cognition and Emotion](http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/pcem20/current)
3. [Social, Cognitive, and Affective Neuroscience](http://scan.oxfordjournals.org)

Looking at journals like these may not be too appealing if you want something quick and easy to read.  But I hope that this is useful to you in some way. :)

Comment: This list is amazing! I'm loving it. Really unfortunate that people (like me) who don't have institutional affiliation can only read the abstracts. I'm cross referencing on Google Scholar, but I gotta find a way around that limitation. Thanks again! This helps a lot.

Comment: @Emile over on Reddit, [/r/scholar](http://www.reddit.com/r/scholar/) can be a good place to request papers, but you didn't hear that from me ;).